# Trigger or simulate hash click

Tags: javascript, jquery, skrollr

I'm having trouble lining up hash clicks due to having parallax scrolling on the page and the only way I found that can easily overcome this, is if when you click a hash link, it is then "clicked again" so it runs twice.  I've tried:

```
$("a[href*='#']").click( function() {
    $(window.location.hash).click(); 
});
```

How could this be done?

Answer (score 0):

It should be this but then it would end up in an infinit loop

```
$("a[href^='#']").click( function() {
    $(this).trigger('click'); 
});
```

Better try this:

```
$("a[href^='#']").on('click', function() {
    $(this).off('click').trigger('click'); 
});
```

if you have other click event attached to these links add a namespace as well:

```
$("a[href^='#']").on('click.mynamespace', function() {
    $(this).off('click.mynamespace').trigger('click'); 
});
```

EDIT:

Adding a timeout will help trigger it twice:

```
$("a[href^='#']").on('click.mynamespace', function() {
    var $self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
       $self.off('click.mynamespace').trigger('click');
    },1);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work either, if you look here http://tristanjc.com/ and click the project links (best example) while at the top of the page, it wont line up, in-till you press again. This code is on the page and console.log'ed.

Comment: There's something different going on. Are there any JS action which alters the dom elements after loading?

Comment: Just some ajax replacing a span and my slider that has element resizing in it. As-well as Skrollr for the parallax.

Comment: It has something todo with the parallax. reload the page and scroll below the projects and clicking will bring you to the expected position. Even if you can "hack" the system by triggering two clicks you should fix the initial problem or you may have problems on other devices for instance

Comment: Oh sorry, i know its the parallax doing this. Their tool do allow hash links to work with skrollr doesn't even fix this problem. Also I have set the parallax to only work on Desktop browsers anyway.

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` (I've updated my answer) to fix your problem but as mentioned I would fix the parallax thing